# Fixed plugin using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Check this template](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/examples/dashboard.html)

1) I have created a fixed plugin using javascript which i have referred from the above template

2) By clicking the icon a card will be open.

3) Inside the card i have created a form using mdb bootstrap.

Everything works fine. When i scroll down, it is fixed, so i could not see the entire form, And i could not make it responsive.

For the reference, i have created my code in codepen. please check it.

[Please check the code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MNaRxj)

```
<div class="icon-bar" style="z-index: 2;">
        <a href="#" class="setting" style="border-radius: 0px 9px 10px 0px;" onclick="cardopen()"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  <div class="container">
        <div id="card" class="card" style="display: none; width: 374px; left: 70px; top: 40px;z-index: 2;position: fixed;">
            <div class="card-body">
<!-- Material input -->
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
  <input type="text" id="form1" class="form-control">
  <label for="form1">Example label</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:left">click here</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">clcking chere</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
<p>testing</p>
<p>testing</p>
<p>testing</p>
<p>testing</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
<p>testing2</p>
<p>testing2</p>
<p>testing2</p>
<p>testing2</p>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 800px;">

    </div>
```

css

```
.icon-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: black;
}

a {
    color: #007bff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #999595;
}
.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}



.setting {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: black;
}
```

js

```
function cardopen() {
  var x = document.getElementById("card");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly

Comment: @B-M I have edited my question. please check it

Answer (score 0):

Hey you just need to follow 2 steps

1 - first set height 100% of fixed div and then

2 - set overflow auto and height 1000% of child div

please check image
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upHXL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply set your 'card' div `display:absolute` instead of `display:fixed` so when you scroll down the sub div (card)  will scroll with page.

```
<div id="card" class="card" style="display: block;width: 374px;left: 70px;top: 40px;z-index: 2;position: absolute;">
```

Or you can set your card menu scroll using this code:

```
<div id="card" class="card" style="display: block;width: 374px;left: 70px;top: 40px;z-index: 2;position: fixed;height: 100%;overflow-x: scroll;">
```